# Can't read responseJSON value in ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

This is the **view** :
[image: picture]

```
{{ Form::open([
       'url' => '/contacts/create',
       'files' => true
])}}
      <div class="row">
          <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
              <div class="col-md-9">
                 {{ Form::label('group', 'group name')}}
                 {{ Form::text('group', null, [
                        'placeholder' => 'Enter group name here',
                        'class' => 'form-control'
                 ])}}
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                  <button id="add-new-btn" class="btn btn-success"><i class="pe-7s-add-user"></i> Add</button>
              </div>
         </div>
      </div>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

in my that view i have this **script**

```
 $("#add-new-btn").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var newGroup = $('#group');
    $.ajax({
        url: "/groups/autocomplete",
        method: "post",
        data: {
            name: $("#group").val(),
            _token: $("input[name=_token]").val()
        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
            var errors = xhr.responseJSON;
            var error = errors.name[0];
            if(error) {
                newGroup.addClass('has-error');
                var inputGroup = newGroup.closest('.col-md-9');
                inputGroup.next('text-danger').remove();

                inputGroup
                    .find('input')
                    .after('<p class="text-danger">' + error + '</p>');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

and in store method of GroupsController i have a simple Validator that may returns these 2 values:
1.The name field is required
2.The name has already been taken

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|unique:groups'
    ]);
}
```

**Now the problem is this  :**
Every time i try to submit the form, the browser returns this error "errors.name is undefined" in console.

where is the problem?
[image: error message]

Comment: Can you please share your HTML(view) as well?

Comment: also did you try this?: `var data=xhr.responseText;
var errors = JSON.parse(data);var error = errors.name[0];`

Comment: @Rakib i tried this too, but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had a mistake for accessing property of object, **jsonData.errors**

```
 var data = xhr.responseText;
 var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
 var msg = jsonData.errors.name[0];
 console.log(msg);
```

or

```
var jsonData = xhr.responseJSON;
var msg = jsonData.errors.name[0];
console.log(msg);
```